# How to handle unreachable ADFS metadata

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, owin, adfs

For my ASP.NET MVC application I'm using ADFS authentication. It is set up in the following manner

```
            app.UseWsFederationAuthentication(
            new WsFederationAuthenticationOptions
            {
                MetadataAddress = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("MetadataAddress"),
                Wtrealm = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("Realm"),
            });
```

Due to something beyond my control, occasionally the metadata at the MetadataAddress is unreachable. In situations like that, I would like to redirect users to a custom view rather than the default error view. How would one accomplish this?

Comment: You might be able to check for the absence of the MetadataAddress and redirect users in that case. This looks like a potentially similar issue... https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/1175

Comment: @MarileeTurscak-MSFT while that link didn't have the solution I was looking for, it did get my creative juices flowing that lead to the solution below. Thank you!

Comment: No problem! Are you able to mark that solution below as the answer to help others find it more easily?

Comment: @MarileeTurscak-MSFT only tomorrow at the earliest :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I've ended up doing is creating Owin Middleware that captures the error that is thrown by invalid metadata that looks like the following and redirects the user to a route describing the issue:

```
public class LoggingMiddleware : OwinMiddleware
{
    public LoggingMiddleware(OwinMiddleware next)
        : base(next)
    {
    }

    public async override Task Invoke(IOwinContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            await Next.Invoke(context);
        } catch(Exception e)
        {
            Logger.Error($"Encountered error in authenticating {e.ToString()}");
            if(e.Source.Equals("Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols"))
            {
                context.Response.Redirect("/Home/OwinError");
            } else
            {
                throw e;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The middleware can simply be added in the startup.cs file with the following line:

```
app.Use(typeof(LoggingMiddleware));
```